# ssh authorized_keys : Configuring single public key for multipl hosts

Tags: ssh

How to use single public key for multiple hosts do i need to duplicate the entries in authorized_keys? or is there a way to do it as single configuration?

For example:
Key user@host1 user@host2 user@host3

Comment: You could generate a key pair, put the public key in the server's `authorized_keys` and share the private key with all your clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server to be accessed remotely, enter the public key (in Ubuntu, contents of `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) for the device the user will be logging in from. This will need to be repeated for all additional servers that it is desired for the user to log in to.

If the user has more than one device used to access the server, then there should be a public key for each device, with each public key on its own line in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: The requirement is to use single public/private key pair to multiple system(cluster) to access a single system. Is there way to achieve it or do we need to generate separate key pairs for each system in cluster?

Comment: There is no technical requirement for each client to have its own private key, just keep in mind that if one client is compromised, then a new private key must be distributed to all clients.

Comment: So we can have a same public key for different hosts in authorized_keys. That's what i take from here. I will try with that. Thanks!